# The axiom related to general topology that has not been mentioned in proofWiki

Tags: general-topology

There are several equivalent definitions of a topological space, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Topology) are the two ones.

---

> Definition $\text{I}$

Let $S$ be a set such that $S≠∅$.

A topology on $S$ is a subset $τ⊆P(S)$ of the power set of $S$ that satisfies the open set axioms:

($O_1$)    : The union of an arbitrary subset of $τ$ is an element of $τ$.
($O_2$)    : The intersection of any two elements of $τ$ is an element of $τ$.
($O_3$)    : $S$ is an element of $τ$.

---

> Definition $\text{II}$
>   Let S be a set such that S≠∅.

A topology on $S$ is a subset $τ⊆P(S)$ of the power set of $S$ that satisfies the following axioms:

($O_{1′}$)    : The union of an arbitrary subset of $τ$ is an element of $τ$.
($O_{2′}$)    : The intersection of any finite subset of $τ$ is an element of $τ$.

---

I know how to prove their equivalency,but there is a problem here,as I know the empty set denoted $\varnothing$ should be contained in $\tau$,but neither definition $\text{I}$ nor definition $\text{II}$ has mentioned that.

The other question is that why $S≠∅$?

Comment: The empty union is the empty set, so the union axiom implies the empty set is open.

Comment: Wow I do not like the way those statements are worded at all. I also think it is a grave mistake to package the statement that $\varnothing, S\in\tau$ with empty unions and intersections.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I agree it's not pretty (in fact, the whole concept of ProofWiki is not very pretty at all). But logically it's correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher 100% agreed for sure. I've had my issues with ProofWiki in the past but this one blows those out of the water for me. Pedagogically this drives me up the wall haha.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,So why Wikipedia has mentioned the axiom explicitly? besides you think the two other axioms are enough to define a topological space?(I mean do you think proofWiki is right?)

Comment: Your last question, why $S\neq\varnothing$, is also what I thought when I read these definitions. I see no reason for that restriction and can only attribute it to $\varnothing$-phobia.

Comment: You would have to ask the person who mentioned the axiom, 715522, not me. Although it is not unknown for systems to be presented with superfluous axioms to make it easier to work with them. The usual axiom lists for vector spaces are redundant (though I don't remember offhand which axiom it is that can be derived from the others).

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm interested to learn what it is about the concept of ProofWiki that makes it "not very pretty at all". At what stage do we pull the plug and say, blow this for a game of soldiers, and throw 12 years of work away?

Comment: @PrimeMover: Soldiers, while rarely thought of as "pretty", have a job to do, and I would hope no-one is making that plug pulling proposal. But all metaphors aside, and since you asked, I'll say: ProofWiki might serve well as a depository for proofs, but I don't think it is well designed as a good place for human beings to learn proofs.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Any suggestions for how it may be improved? There's a perception that it's a great big pile of effluent, which is disheartening for those who thought they were onto doing something useful.

Comment: @LeeMosher,I totally agree, besides sometimes the pages are full of unnecessary mathematical notations and some other notations that are rarely used in standard mathematics books.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Is there a good place to carry on this discussion other than in this comment thread? Perhaps some place on the ProofWiki site itself?

Comment: @user715522: Not in the body of the text. In an "also known as" or "also denoted as" section, where alternative notations are discussed. (This is to keep happy those people who know a different notation and hence don't understand the page otherwise. You'd be surprised how many that may be.)  Like a dictionary provides examples of usage and alternative spellings and so on, ProofWiki tries to do with mathematical proofs and definitions. Please cite examples where this is intrusive.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Feel free to set up an account there and join the discussion that is being held at the moment on the general chat page there, on the appalling reputation ProofWiki has throughout the civilised universe.

Answer (score 3):

The rely on the logical "trick" of empty unions and empty intersections:

If we take $\emptyset \subseteq \tau$ in $O'_1$ and $O'_2$ (allowed because $\emptyset$ is a (finite) subset of any set) we get that:

$\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset \in \tau$ and $\bigcap \emptyset =S \in \tau$, where the latter is justified by $$\forall x \in S: x \in \bigcap \emptyset \iff \forall O' \in \emptyset: x \in O'$$ where the statement on the right hand side is true because we use a universal quantor over an empty domain ([vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)), and we quantify over $S$ on the left because we are working inside the power set of $S$.

It's a bit "tricky", but is used here to get a more economical set of axioms (2 instead of 3), even though in practice this has little importance and $S$ and $\emptyset$ are often explicitly checked anyway when we're proving a set to be a topology.

In short, a minor point of sophistry of little didactical value, possibly only causing confusion in beginning students.